# Python: adding two dicts together

Tags: python

Alrigt, lets say I have these two dictionaries:

```
A = {(3,'x'):-2, (6,'y'):3, (8, 'b'):9}
B = {(3,'y'):4, (6,'y'):6}
```

I am trying to add them together such that I get a dict similar to this:

```
C = {(3,'x'):-2,(3,'y'):4, (6,'y'):9, (8, 'b'):9}
```

I have tried making a comprehension that does this for dicts of any lenght. But it seems a bit difficult for a newbie. I am at a level where I try stuff like this for example:

Edited:

```
>>> {k:A[k]+B[d] for k in A for d in B}
{(6, 'y'): 7, (3, 'x'): 2, (8, 'b'): 13}
```

I get this far due to help but it leaves out the 
(3,'y'):4 for some reason

Comment: `A.keys` is a function. `A.keys()` is the result of calling the function on dictionary `A`.

Comment: You don't want the double `for`. That'll iterate over every key in `B` once for every key in `A`; effectively, it'll iterate over every combination of a key from `A` and a key from `B`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're using Python 3, one possible approach would be:

```
>>> A = {(3,'x'):-2, (6,'y'):3, (8, 'b'):9}
>>> B = {(3,'y'):4, (6,'y'):6}
>>> {k: A.get(k,0) + B.get(k,0) for k in A.keys() | B.keys()}
{(8, 'b'): 9, (3, 'x'): -2, (6, 'y'): 9, (3, 'y'): 4}
```

In Python 3, `.keys()` returns a `dict_keys` object, and we can use the `|` operator to take the union of the two.  (That's why `A.keys() + B.keys()` won't work.)

(I'd probably use a `Counter` myself, FWIW.)

Comment: Yeah, man... You guys make some really easy to read and impressive codes.

Comment: or you could use :
>>> C = dict(A, **B) # python 2.7
>>> C = dict(list(A.items()) + list(B.items())

Answer (score 11):

I would use a [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this:

```
>>> A = {(3,'x'):-2, (6,'y'):3, (8, 'b'):9}
>>> B = {(3,'y'):4, (6,'y'):6}
>>> import collections
>>> C = collections.Counter(A)
>>> C.update(B)
>>> dict(C)
{(3, 'y'): 4, (8, 'b'): 9, (3, 'x'): -2, (6, 'y'): 9}
```

Comment: That works, but is it possible to return just a normal dict? without the Counter?

Comment: You can convert your Counter object into a dictionary using the `dict()` function. `dictionary = dict(counterobject)`

Comment: Updated answer to show it being turned back into a dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

Iterate over a list of keys from A and B

```
>>> A = {(3,'x'):-2, (6,'y'):3, (8, 'b'):9}
>>> B = {(3,'y'):4, (6,'y'):6}
>>> C = dict()
>>> for key in set(A.keys() + B.keys()):
...     C[key] = A.get(key, 0) + B.get(key, 0)
... 
>>> C
{(3, 'y'): 4, (8, 'b'): 9, (3, 'x'): -2, (6, 'y'): 9}
```

Comment: `for key in set(A.keys() + B.keys()):` otherwise you're doing it twice for keys that are in both (though you'll get the right answer).

Comment: I get "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_keys' and 'dict_keys'" That might be because I am running Python 3, I should have mentioned that I guess

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the most efficient method, but it's more general.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
A = {(3,'x'):-2, (6,'y'):3, (8, 'b'):9}
B = {(3,'y'):4, (6,'y'):6}

dd={}
for d in (A, B): #Put as many dictionaries as you would like here
  for key, value in d.iteritems():
    dd[key] = dd.get(key, 0) + value
```

Comment: I'd make the inner loop read: `dd[key] = dd.get(key, 0) + value` if you wanted to take that approach.

Comment: Thanks, Kirk, that's a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be:

```
for i in dictA.items():
    if i[0] not in dictA:
        dictB[i[0]] = i[1]
    else:
        dictB[i[0]] = dictB[i[0]] + i[1]
```

Which is probably the least fancy one here

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a comprehension.

```
A = {(3,'x'):-2, (6,'y'):3, (8, 'b'):9}
B = {(3,'y'):4, (6,'y'):6}

C = {k:A.get(k, 0) + B.get(k, 0) for k in set(A.keys() + B.keys())}

print C
# {(3, 'y'): 4, (8, 'b'): 9, (3, 'x'): -2, (6, 'y'): 9}
```

What this does is combines the keys and removes any duplicates. Then it simply adds together the values from each key. If either A or B doesn't have one of the values, you just get the value from the other dict.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_keys' and 'dict_keys'

Answer (score 1):

```
#Needed if you're using python3
from functools import reduce    

A = {(3,'x'):-2, (6,'y'):3, (8, 'b'):9}
B = {(3,'y'):4, (6,'y'):6}

#Merging all the key/value(s) inside one big list
C = list(A.items()) + list(B.items())
#C = [((3,'x'), -2), ((6,'y'), 3), ...]    

#Keeping a list of all unique (hence the set) keys available
keys = set([key[0] for key in C])
#keys = set([(3,'x'), (6,'y'), ...])

result = {}
for key in keys:
    #Extracing the pairs that corresponds to the current key
    local = [item for item in C if item[0] == key]
    #local = [((6,'y'), 3), ((6,'y'), 6)]

    #Actually doing the sum and storing the ready to insert result
    my_sum = reduce(lambda x,y: (x[0], x[1] + y[1]), local)
    #my_sum = [((6,'y'), 9)]

    #Actually inserting the result into the result set
    result.update({my_sum[0]: my_sum[1]})
    #result.update({(6,'y'): 9})

>>> result
{(3, 'y'): 4, (8, 'b'): 9, (3, 'x'): -2, (6, 'y'): 9}
```

Comment: Once I read 'newbie' in your question's body, I've triggered my comments madness mode ^^